# Closing jQuery Modal box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I'm trying to create a basic modal myself and I'm having a little bit trouble here (maybe it's because I'm an expert working with jQuery - don't take it seriously).

I have this HMTL markup:

```
<div id="modal-boxes">
    <div id="modal-updates" class="modal-content">
        Content for modal box here.
        <a href="#" class="close-modal">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="modal-mask"></div>
```

So, I made a function that tells the modal box to close and to make disappear the #mask div. And another one to when I click outside of it, it closes anyway. In other words, clicking outside the #modal-updates div is the same that clicking on close button. But the problem is that when I want to click inside the #modal-updates div (should not disappear) it closes anyway. Here is my javascript code:

```
$(".modal").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault(); // Cancel the default link behavior

    $("#modal-mask").fadeTo(400, 0.4);
    $("#modal-boxes").fadeIn();

    var getName = "#" + $(this).attr("name");
    $(getName).fadeTo(400, 1);
});

function closeModal() {
    $("#modal-mask, #modal-boxes").fadeOut();
}

$(".close-modal").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    closeModal();
});

$(".modal-content").click(function(){
    closeModal();
});
```

Any help?

Regards, Tiago Castro

Comment: Can you show a demo of the issue?

Comment: yes you can: http://jsfiddle.net/webtiago/z6Z6w/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#modal-updates').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

If done right, this will stop `$("#modal-boxes").click()` from triggering.

[edit] fixed a typo and added link to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6Z6w/4/) with it working

Comment: No problem. Been through the exact same thing a time or two.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the modal dialog of jQuery?

About your example :

1) for the link I prefer to do something like:

```
<a href="javascript:void(closeMyPopup());" class="close-modal">Close</a>
```

That way no need to deal with things like preventDefault or click event

2)I guess that instead of binding your click event to ".modal-content" you wanted to bind it to "#modal-mask" ;)

Comment: jQuery modal? ...do you mean jQuery UI, maybe?